# Where in this simple code could fire SIGABRT? (gcc 4.9.2)

Tags: c++

I was solving https://algospot.com/judge/problem/read/LUNCHBOX when this simple code fired SIGABRT error. It runs perfectly on my local environment but it doesn't on the site. Where could this go wrong?  could it be resize? or scanf?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

int main(void)
{
    using namespace std;
    vector<pair<int, int>> lunchbox;

    int t;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    while (t--)
    {
        int n;
        scanf("%d", &n);
        lunchbox.resize(n, make_pair(0, 0));
        for (auto &box : lunchbox)
            scanf("%d", &box.first);
        for (auto &box : lunchbox)
            scanf("%d", &box.second);

        sort(lunchbox.begin(), lunchbox.end(),
                 [](pair<int, int> &i, pair<int, int> &j)
                 { return i.second >= j.second; });

        int lunchtime = 0;
        int eating_time_left = 0;
        for (auto &box : lunchbox)
        {
            lunchtime += box.first;
            eating_time_left = max(eating_time_left - box.first, box.second);
        }
        lunchtime += eating_time_left;
        printf("%d\n", lunchtime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Q: Where in this simple code could fire SIGABRT? (gcc 4.9.2)?  A: That's what [stack traces](https://senarvi.github.io/stack-trace-with-gdb/) are for.  Compile your code with "-g", run it in GDB (or equivalent) and you'll be able to see EXACTLY what led up to the crash.

Comment: The sort comparator violates the requirements ([strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Axiomatizations)).  Probably lead to a stack overflow (*ironic!*) and then SIGABRT nanoseconds thereafter.

Comment: @paulsm4 Thanks, will research on that from now on

Comment: @Eljay For my understanding, the comparator passed to std::sort must be strict weak ordering and should not return true when lhs == rhs (i.e. should be lhs > rhs or lhs < rhs), since the induced relation should only be true when lhs == rhs, am i right?

Comment: When you see `>=` or `<=` in a comparator function you could be looking at death. in `i.second >= j.second;` you will get true if `i.second == j.second`, so `i` belongs before  `j` but `j` belongs before `i`. Mr. Spock does not approve of this logic.